# select 8 rows in the table and calculate statistics for them, then select next 8 in the same table and calculate statistics for them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, statistics, python-parser

I have a large table which structure looks like that:

[image: table, data structure]

This is just to show you what I want to achieve, because my original table has nearly 1 million records.

Now imagine that I have temperature values calculated for every region which is represented by column geoid.

In this example I have 4 regions. For each region I have temperature values calculated 2 x daily for every day in a year.

What I need to get, is to calculate max temperature value for each day, thus in this example I need something which let me:

select first 8 rows -> calculate max temp. value for each geoid -> then select next 8 rows -> calculate max temp. value for new selection.

I need this to repeat for every day in a whole year.

How can I do this?

Comment: This sounds like a really tedious way to accomplish  what could be a single Python cursor query if you calculate the statistics.on your own.  Either way,  it's GIS SE policy to include code in coding questions, so you'll need to at least make an attempt before we can help fix any issues.

Comment: You should start by creating a field for date values and populate it with your dates (or just day of year if that's enough). OIDs are not static and you shouldn't base a calculation like this on them.